# Most efficient way for testing links

Tags: c#, sockets, web-crawler, webrequest

I'm currently developping an app that is going through all the files on a server and checking every single hrefs to check wether they are valid or not. Using a WebClient or a HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse is kinda overkilling the process because it downloads the whole page each time, which is useless, I only need to check if the link do not return 404.

What would be the most efficient way? Socket seems to be a good way of doing it, however I'm not quite sure how this works.

Thanks for sharing your expertise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient would be to send the `HEAD` verb to preserve bandwidth.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/");
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // 200 OK
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explicit answer, however, just wondering why you are using var instead of httpWebResponse? Could it return an exception?

Comment: No, it's only because `var` is shorter than `HttpWebResponse` :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still too slow, let me know if anyone else has a another answer

Answer (score 1):

Set [`HttpWebRequest.Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to "`Head`". This will only receive the headers.